# industrial qr code scanner: automatic login and browser new tab for url verification

Tags: wordpress, bash, curl, qr-code, lynx

sorry for the long (and too wide) title but I have the following problem.

I have set up a ticketing system in my WP blog (for a music school): people can freely register for a concert and receive an email with a ticket containing a generated QR code which is simply an URL for an internal page. I can verify the URL just logging in the blog and then visiting the URL.
I have an industrial QR code scanner (Datalogic Quickscan QB T2400) which works out of the box: I scan the ticket and it returns the URL.

The problem is that I have to:
 1. manually open a browser
 2. manually log in my WP blog
 3. manually open a new tab for each ticket URL (before scanning)

This is not good, especially because we make concerts in different venues and I need only to have the scanner with me (not necessarily a computer terminal).

Is there a way to make the whole process with a bash script?

I have tried with some textual browser in bg but they are not connecting to my blog...

```
#! /bin/bash

function check_url() {
read -p "URL to check: " url
if curl --output /dev/null --silent --head --fail "$url"; then
  xterm -e lynx -accept_all_cookies $url &
  printf '%s\n' "$url exist"

else
  printf '%s\n' "$url does not exist"
fi
check_url
}

lynx -accept_all_cookies -auth=DOMAIN\\ID:PW &
check_url
```

Curl hits the URL correctly but lynx is not logging in (and hence no verification is done).

If you have any tips, thanks in advance.

nicgios

ps. I'm working in a Debian environment.

Comment: It may be simpler if you use a smartphone which scan the QR code and open a browser. That can be a solution ?

Comment: Yes: that's simple (and it works, already tested) but it's too slow! :) I mean: point the phone, take the correct focus, scan it, etc. When you have 150 people attending it can be painful. With a scanner (like the one we have purchased) you just scan it: it's a matter of milliseconds. Phones and tablets are good for scanning a single QR code, not a large quantity...

Comment: If you have a several people to welcome, you have juste to open the browser on time ? How exactly works the scanner, if you have the focus on a text field, does the result of the QR Code appears in this field ?

Comment: Thanks for your prompt comments mmm!
Answering to your question: the scanner is like a supermarket one. It is linked to a base and send data to the base. The base is usb-linked to a computer and receives data. If I open a terminal (i.e. xterm but also any other apps like a browser, gnumeric, lowriter, etc) data in the QR code are correctly displayed (i.e. the URL).

Comment: Another problem we have is that we don't have wifi in the building: so the idea is to plug the scanner base into a computer (online with eth cable) and then to move around the bulding with the scanner (we make concerts in different rooms of the building, not only in the concert hall).

Comment: I'm not sure to understant how it works. If it is not pluged to a computer, does the base stack the values ? I ask you about the text field because if the data is send to a text field, a JavaScript traitement can read it and answer directly ... euh ... what is the answer ? Do you verify the result, e.g. to test if the QR Code is valid ?